# What kind of wire connectors are these?

Tags: connector, identification, test-equipment

The loop ones. I've never seen them before.

[image: none]

Comment: Apart from the fine answers already here, I'd like to add that test points like these are rarely populated in actual production PCBs. They're usually only found in evaluation kit boards and prototypes. On production boards, the positions are often either left unpopulated, replaced with test pads (for automated bed-of-nails testing) or removed from the design altogether.

Comment: Depends on what industry your in, in mine we do a lot of testing on our boards, most of the older designs have these on our production boards

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They are test points, as shown [here](http://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Test-Points-Tips-Probes-Clips/Test-Points-color-keyed-Thru-Hole-Mount/p/518/id/521/).

[image]

They are suitable for mini-grabber connections to lab equipment or probing

Answer (score 28):

TP is the designator for ***Test Point***.

The plastic part just moves the loop part off the board, but you can see some without the plastic part. Nothing more than a small looped section of conductive wire. They can function as jumpers at the same time.

They are used for test clips to grab onto.

[image]

Some other options are 2 dimensional holes:

[image]

Comment: Do you by chance remember how these particular components are named?

Comment: Test point loops brings up results.

Comment: Yes, but the ones posted by OP have a specific name I don't recall.

Comment: @mast https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/color-coded-test-points/19725 *shrug*

Answer (score 13):

As others say, these are test points.  The coloured plastic rings can be used to indicate the type of signal on that test point.  On the board in your picture, it appears that black testpoints are Ground.  Red is for power - I see one labelled "+3.3V".

Answer (score 12):

Test points for scope-probe hooks to grab securely.